# Why element.setAttribute('checked', true) doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to do something like this:

```
elementX.setAttribute('checked', true); // this is input type checkbox
elementY.appendChild(elementX);
```

It is everything ok with rendering and other things but on the page, the input is not checked.
When I look at elements in chrome console I can see:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="true">
```

What should I do?

I've already tried

```
elementX.setAttribute('checked', true);
elementX.setAttribute('checked', 'true');
elementX.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
```

I don't have any errors in the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#checked):

> checked
>
> A Boolean attribute indicating whether or not this checkbox is checked by default (when the page loads). It does **not** indicate whether this checkbox is currently checked: if the checkbox’s state is changed, this content attribute does not reflect the change. (Only the HTMLInputElement’s checked IDL attribute is updated.).

While setting the `checked` attribute will show a change in the serialization of the element, it won't actually check the checkbox. For that, you have to invoke the setter, eg

```
elementX.checked = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly, @CertainPerformance answer is the one that I upvoted, and it's correct!*

I simply wanted to shed more light on the nuances of IDL( Interface Design Language ) attributes versus content attributes and what it means for them to be  **reflective** or not.

In this case an IDL attribute is a JavaScript Property on a DOM representation of an Element. Not just any property, but one that was predefined within the W3 Specification. [IDL Examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/idl-definitions.html)

Attributes specified in your HTML are considered **content attributes**. These attributes are used to populate **IDL attributes** on DOM Nodes during the rendering process. **content attributes** are accessible from the DOM Node through a few ways including the `getAttribute` method, but they are not stored on it as **IDL attributes** are. In simple terms `element.getAttribute("checked")` and `element.checked` are actually looking in two completely different objects for the key *checked*.

So what's it mean to be **reflective?**

A DOM Node's `property` and its HTML `attribute` are interchangeable from the point of rendering if the node is not altered - but also if **specific** attributes are changed.

Altering `id` and `class` in any way, whether directly on the DOM Node or within the Attribute object using the `element.setAttribute` method, will result in *both* values being changed.

`id` and `class` are **reflective** IDL attributes because they, in effect, watch their content attributes for changes and vice versa.

Alternatively `checked` and `value` IDL attributes are **not reflective**. When the `value` or `checked` properties are altered on either the DOM Node or the Attribute Object, it does not alter the corresponding attributes of the other.

*Outside of those properties*( there are more than `id` and `class` - though there's [no real list of reflective vs not reflective](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes) - I would presume it's any property related to the identity of the Node in the DOM that would cause a re-render ) the **content attributes** and **DOM Node properties** are not bound together. This makes using `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` useless if the intent is to update or get *current data*, because the *current data* is only found within the **DOM Node properties**.

The examples below illustrate the difference:

---

### ID change example: Both Attribute and Property Reflect Each Other

```js
let i = document.querySelector("input");

i.addEventListener("id_change", function() {
let HTML_Attribute = i.getAttribute("id"),
    DOM_Node_Property = i.id;
    
    console.log("HTML Attribute 'value': " + HTML_Attribute +
             "\n DOM Node Property 'value': " + DOM_Node_Property);
})


let n = 1;
let timer = setInterval(function() {
if(n > 2) clearInterval(timer);
i.setAttribute("id", "newId_" + String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 65));
i.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("id_change"));
n++;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input value="Hello World"/>
```

---

### Value change example: Attribute and Property Are Different

```js
let i = document.querySelector("input");

i.addEventListener("input", function() {
let HTML_Attribute = i.getAttribute("value"),
    DOM_Node_Property = i.value;
    
    console.log("HTML Attribute 'value': " + HTML_Attribute +
             "\n DOM Node Property 'value': " + DOM_Node_Property);
})
```

```html
<input value="Hello World"/> <em><small>Type into the Box</small></em>
```